# How to convert numeric string from a sublist in Python

Tags: python, list, integer, numeric, sublist

I'm a freshie. I would like to convert a numeric string into int from a sublist in Python. But not getting accurate results.

```py
countitem = 0
list_samp = [['1','2','blue'],['1','66','green'],['1','88','purple']]

for list in list_samp:
  countitem =+1
  for element in list:
    convert_element = int(list_samp[countitem][0])
    list_samp[countitem][1] = convert_element
```

Comment: `[[int(i) if i.isdecimal() else i for i in l] for l in list_samp]`

Comment: Your inner loop seems completely unnecessary, you are not even using `element` anywhere inside it. Do you want to convert the first element to int or all elements that can be converted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
list_samp = [['1','2','blue'],['1','66','green'],['1','88','purple']]
me = [[int(u) if u.isdecimal() else u for u in v] for v in list_samp]
print(me)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it:

```
list_samp = [['1','2','blue'],['1','66','green'],['1','88','purple']]
list_int = [[int(i) if i.isdecimal() else i for i in l] for l in list_samp]
print(list_int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the process step-by-step

```py
countitem = 0
list_samp = [['1','2','blue'],['1','66','green'],['1','88','purple']]

#Let's traverse through the list
for list in list_samp:  #gives each list
  for i in range(len(list)): # get index of each element in sub list
    if list[i].isnumeric(): # Check if all characters in the string is a number
      list[i] = int(list[i]) # store the converted integer in the index i
```